# Excel: Is it possible to bind cells in a row together based on value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have recently used [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) solution to create a dynamically generated list of uniques.

What it does is it takes cell values (here: list of names) and generates another list without repetition. Let's say next to those names I wanted to have comments about those names. However, if I add more names (especially if the formula is extended to apply sorting), the **unique names** and **comments** columns become misaligned.

Is it possible to make a cell with comment that will “change rows” along with it’s go-to value in any way without using VBA?

I am aware I am copying database behavior, but please assume this needs to be done in Excel (or Google Sheets).

**EDIT: Additional info:**

What I meant is to somehow bind/update column F to keep it fixed against it's counterpart cell in column E.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: By Comments do you mean Excel's inline comments in a box that attaches itself to a cell or you plan to use an adjacent cell in next column (say Column C) to put some comments about names in Column B?

Comment: Can you post some sample data (a screenshot here may help) of what you have, and what you'd like to do?  I *think* you might benefit from using named ranges?

Comment: Updated post to accomodate your questions.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, it sounds like you have a list of names in Col A with duplicates and random order.  You use a process to extract the unique names and put them in Col E.  Then you manually enter comments in Col F.  Later you want to add names to Col A, maybe sort, and rerun the process that puts the unique names in Col E.  After that, the Col F comments are no longer aligned.  If that's essentially it, the problem is that there is no real connection between the unique names and the comments, they just happen to occupy adjacent columns.  (cont'd)

Comment: To relate them, you need something that permanently associates them (a table that doesn't change when you enter or manipulate the Col A data).  That table needs to be separate from the Col E results that are subject to revision.  The gist would be to create a master table somewhere else.  You could use your existing routine to create an initial list of unique names.  Once you do, you need a different process to add to it so that you don't disrupt the previous data.  Put the comments in that table, and add comments as you add names.  (cont'd)

Comment: Don't worry about sorting that table, or even deleting old names.  That becomes a lookup table.  Now, you can independently do anything you want with the Col E list.  Create it or recreate it from Col A as needed, sort it, etc.  You fill in the comments in Col F by looking up the name in Col E against your master table and returning the associated value (commonly using VLOOKUP).

Comment: Okay, I see. If you put that as as answer, I will accept it :)

Comment: @MrVocabulary, just FYI, if you don't address comments with @, nobody will be aware of them unless they happen to stumble across them (which is how I noticed your last comment).  :-)

Comment: @fixer I forgot that notifs are by default only to the answers, my bad! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no real connection between the unique names and the comments, they just happen to occupy adjacent columns.  To relate them, you need something that permanently associates them (a table that doesn't change when you enter or manipulate the Column A data).  That table needs to be separate from the Column E results that are subject to revision.

The gist would be to create a master table somewhere else. You could use your existing routine to create an initial list of unique names. Once you do, you need a different process to add to it so that you don't disrupt the previous data. Put the comments in that table, and add comments as you add names.  Don't worry about sorting that table, or even deleting old names. That becomes a lookup table.

Now, you can independently do anything you want with the Column E list. Create it or recreate it from Column A as needed, sort it, etc.  You fill in the comments in Column F by looking up the name in Column E against your master table and returning the associated value (that's commonly done using [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)).